# How is dartfish.com coded?

Tags: html, clone

I am trying to create my own personal cv website.  I love how www.dartfish.com looks and would like to base it on that, obviously losing the sports theme and changing the colours.

Does anyone know where I could start?  I know I could make it easy by using a Wordpress theme, but thats not what I want.  I am trying to learn whilst I code.

Thank you for your time

Comment: I'm afraid this question comes off as way too broad and is asking many things at once. It's hard to know where you should start. How much experience do you have with web development? Do you know `javascript`, `html`, and `css`? Do you know any frameworks?

Comment: If you want to copy that website, you can literally copy all of their CSS, JS & HTML.

Comment: While the previous comment may have been intended as humorous, copying all of the content of a website would most likely constitute a violation of copyright. In either case, this question seems too broad and open-ended, and is not about software development or a specific development problem per se, so I'm flagging to close it.

Comment: That design is so generic I bet you could find a WP theme that looks just like it in about 10 minutes.... Good luck! 
https://themeforest.net/category/wordpress

Comment: I'm sorry that it sounded generic.

I have a 1st class degree in web systems development so have experience (non professional) in HTML/CSS/PHP

My question was asking about dartfish.com and which language do you think it was coded in?

With that knowledge I can start creating a website with a similar layout but completely different (non-sports related).  I don't want. carbon copy, I just want to push my knowledge and learn from coding.

Also, I know I could find a WP theme that matches this, but I want to hand code from scratch.

Thank you for your time.